# subdivision surface is not working on geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, mesh, node-editor, subdivision-surface, geometry-nodes

[image]

I've added a mesh subdivide to the cube, but it doesn't work. how to add a subdivision surface through geometry nodes?

Comment: You're using a Beta version (3.0) of Blender which won't be officially released until December so you can expect some problems with it!

Answer (score 2):

It works, you just don't "see" it directly.

Another example:

[image]

If you instance something (e.g. a sphere), you can see that your geometry was subdivided.

[image]

Another way to "see" it:

Check your spreadsheet: here you see more than just 8 vertices...

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris for taking your time to answer this question, is this a bug or is it how it's supposed to work?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. There are also some other modifiers (and GN is a modifier too) where you can see the result only if you apply the modifier. e.g. decimate modifier. You won't see where he deleted the vertices before. You only see the result when you apply it. Same here. If you apply the GN modifier, you will see the subdivisions if you press tab to edit mode.

Comment: even the subdivision modifier itself cannot show the vertices: it shows the new mesh form, but you cannot press tab or something else to see the newly added vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The subdivision surface modifier has been split into two separate nodes.

The first node, "Subdivide Mesh", replaces the "Simple" option on the subdivision surface modifier:
[image]

The second node, "Subdivision Surface", replaces the "Catmull-Clark" option:
[image]